# Find the derivative of a left-translation map

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

I'm studying left-translation maps and left-invariant vector fields for Lie groups.
Vector addition is the group operation in this case.
Let *v* $\in$ $\Bbb R$<sup>*n*</sup>.
For $$L_v: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$$
I found the left-translation map -

$$L_v= v+x$$

I'm trying to find the derivative $dL_v$ of said left-translation map.
If I take the derivative, I just get $1$. Something tells me it's a bit more complicated than that. Is there special way of taking the derivative of a left-translation map? What would $dL_v$ be in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That seems correct to me. Note that the way you are identifying each tangent space with the vector space itself is, in effect, just the inverse of the translation map (left or right, they are the same here) so the left translation map then just looks like the identity.

Comment: Thanks! turns out that it is just the identity